# How to execute an array of observables sequentially?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an dynamically created array of observables (which make http requests to backend). Something like:

```
let observables: Observable<any>[] = [ $obs1, $obs2 ];

if(someCondition)
  observables.push($obs3);

if(someOtherCondition)
  observables.push($obs4);

 forkJoin(observables).subscribe();
```

This way the observables are executed in parallel like:

```
$obs1  >>>>>>
$obs2  >>>>>>>
$obs3  >>>>>>>>
```

I Would like to execute one after other, something like:

```
$obs1  >>>>>>
$obs2        >>>>>>>
$obs3               >>>>>>>>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `concat(...observables).subscribe();`

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the array into a big switchMap

```
observables.reduce((o1$,o2$) => o1$.pipe(switchMap(o1 => o2$));
```

When you subscribe they will run one after the other.